# How to access a random generated integer from other class without generating other random number

Tags: java, variables, random

I have two classes

Class 1

```
public class Random {

    public static int random() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(10);
    }
    public static int number = random();
}
```

And Class 2

```
public class SecondClass {
    
    static int generatedNumber = Random.number;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println(generatedNumber);
    }
}
```

Every time I try to access the generatedNumber variable of Class 2 from a third Class, the number I get is different and not the one received in Class 2.

My question is how I can make the number generated in Class 2 persist to be able to call it from other Classes and that it is always the same number generated in Class 2.

Comment: I'm confused ... do you want a random number, or always the same one?

Comment: Rather than calling things "Class 1/2/third class", could you just refer to them by their name: Random/FirstClass? It's confusing that Class 2 is FirstClass. Also, please show the third class.

Comment: (It would probably help your problem if you made these fields `final` if possible).

Comment: @Stultuske I want to generate that random number once and then access it from other classes without it being generated again.

Comment: You want your random class to do two things, to repeat an old random number and to send a new random number.  That means you need two methods, one to retrieve the old number and one to generate a new random number.

Comment: @rossum No, I don't want to repeat a random number, I want to access the number generated without generating another number.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue when created a 3rd class referring the 2nd class `static int generatedNumber = SecondClass.generatedNumber;` -- all three numbers are the same.  Please show how you access `SecondClass.generatedNumber` field from the third class.

Comment: If you only want the one random number then use the constructor to set up a single static variable.  Then write a `getOldRandom()` method to return the value of that static variable.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I try to access it with SecondClass.generatedNumber but every time I do that I get a different number

Comment: @rossum I don't know how to do that, can you show it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked me to show you:

```
public class FixRandom {

    // Holds the fixed random value.
    private final int fixedValue;

    // Upper bound for the RNG.
    private static final int BOUND = 10;

    // Constructor.
    public FixRandom() {
        // Set the fixed random value.
        Random rand = new Random();
        fixedValue = rand.nextInt(BOUND);
    }

    // Method to access the fixed random value.
    public int getFixRandom() {
        return fixedValue;
    }

}
```

When you need to retrieve the number, use the `getFixRandom()` method.